# Possible to have Mongoose return a connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

When using eg. MySQL, one open a connection fx:

```
const c = await mysql.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost',
     user: 'x',
     password: 'x',
     database: 'x',
     Promise: bluebird,
  });
```

and then perform actions on the connection `c` like so

```
const [rows, fields] = await c.execute(q);
```

but with Mongoose `mongoose.connect()` [doesn't return a connection](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#server-selection). it is nice not that it "just works", but I really would prefer the MySQL approach where it is explicitly written which database connection that is used.

Is that possible with Mongoose?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have opened a connection with `mongoose.connect()`, you can then perform actions with `mongoose.connection`:

```js
mongoose.connect(connectionString)
const c = mongoose.connection
```

Comment: Can you give an example with mongoose.Schema(), mongoose.model(), mongoose.create() ?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting what do you mean? The connection is set on module level to benefit from module caching. Think about it as a singleton, it's just `mongoose.connection`, not related to Schema or model really.

Comment: @AlexBlex Interesting! Is it possible to have Mongoose disable module caching, so a connection have to be used with `mongoose.create()`, `mongoose.find()`, etc... ?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting module caching is part of nodejs, not mongoose: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#caching. Now, mongo is very different from mysql. The client is much thicker, is aware about server's topology, and maintains a pool of permanently open connections to the cluster.  The complexity is hidden within mongodb driver https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/ - the module used by mongoose under the hood.  If you don't like mongoose magic you will be better off using the driver directly. Otherwise you will be fighting mongoose instead of using it.

Comment: Is there any way to create a function to cache the connection so the connection is only created one time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mongoose.createConnection()` function takes the same arguments as `mongoose.connect()` and returns a new connection.

```
const conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]', options);
```

This connection object is then used to create and retrieve models. Models are always scoped to a single connection.

```
const UserModel = conn.model('User', userSchema);
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections